# How to use the return value of a function in a linq where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a general search query against an EF entity type (person). In general, the search takes a string, splits it by commas, and then searches for people whose various attributes contain all of the key words.

I have a function called getProperties(Person p) that takes an entity (overridden by entity type), and returns a string of the various relevant properties joined together with a delimiter... such as:

```
John~Doe~Team A~Full Time
```

If the user searches for "Team A, Full" person corresponding to the above flattened entity should be returned... however, if the enter "John, Smith" it shouldn't.

I think the following looks right, but it just doesn't work...

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchPeople(string searchString)
{
    if (searchString == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString.Trim()))
        return base._objectSet.ToList();

    string[] SearchWords = searchString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

    return (from    person 
            in      base._objectSet 
            let     t = (getProperties(person)) 
            where   SearchWords.All(word => t.Contains(word)) 
            select  person).ToList();
}
```

and the getProperties function is:

```
public static string getProperties(Person p)
{
    string[] values = { p.Surname, p.GivenName, p.Team, p.Status };
    return values.Aggregate((x, y) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(y) ? x : string.Concat(x, "~", y));
}
```

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**Edit**

No exceptions are raised, but when I step through the code, when I get to the linq, it steps into the dispose method of the unitofwork that is hosting the query. Very odd.

If I change it so that it searches against a hard-coded string, it works as expected:

```
var test = (from    person 
            in      base._objectSet 
            where   SearchWords.All(word => "John~Doe~Team A~Full Time".Contains(word))
            select person).ToList();
```

well, it works in that it matches the queries I expect it to, but as it's static, it returns every person record (pretty much like having where(true) =P)

**Edit the Second**

Even odder is that if I store the results into a var, then return the var with a breakpoint on the return, execution never hits the breakpoint... this linq is like a black hole... I can step into it, but it never returns me back to my SearchPeople method... it just disposes the context and forgets about it.

**Edit the Third**

If I don't call ToString() right away and look at the linq expression in debugger, it says "Linq to Entities does not recognize the method getProperties(Person)" Looks like it was silently choking on my method... any way to use my method without linq choking on it?

Comment: Can you explain why 'it just doesn't work?'

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a List? try the return type to be a List or change the `.ToList()` to be `AsEnumerable()`

```
public List<Person> SearchPeople(string searchString)
{
    if (searchString == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString.Trim()))
        return base._objectSet.ToList();

    string[] SearchWords = searchString.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

    return (from    person 
            in      base._objectSet 
            let     t = (getProperties(person)) 
            where   SearchWords.All(word => t.Contains(word)) 
            select  person).ToList();
}
```

Comment: List gets an implicit conversion to IEnumerable. Makes no difference as far as I can see. I tested it just in case I was wrong, but nothing changed when using List.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after finding out that linq 2 entites doesn't like methods (as is doesn't know how to translate it to sql), i rewrote my linq is a very tedious but functioning manner:

```
var people = from    p
             in      base._objectSet
             where   SearchWords.All(p.GivenName.Contains(word) || p.Surname.Contains(word) || p.(???).Contains(word) || etc.)
                    select p;
```

Annoying, but there you go.